# What guarentees the existance of scalar function $λ?$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Suppose all the tangent lines of a space curve pass through a fixed point. What can we say about the curve?

**Proof starts like this in the textbook**

Without loss of generality, we take the fixed point to be the origin and the curve to be arc length-parametrized by $\vec α$. Then for every s we have $\vec α(s) = λ(s)\vec T(s)$ for
some scalar function $λ.$
I have a doubt here. What guarentees the existance of  scalar function $λ?$

**My attempt:-**
I know the $\vec α'(s)$ indicate the direction of tangent vector to the curve $\vec α(s)$. $\vec α'(s)=\vec{T}(s).$ I couldn't find the scope of $\lambda$. Could you help me?

Comment: Draw a picture. Since $\vec{T}$ is tangent to the curve $\vec{\alpha}$ you effectively add /subtract two vectors. Make $\vec{T}$ long enough and you will hit the origin (by assumption on your curve).

Comment: @KurtG. I couldn't unnderstand.

Comment: Could you explain bit more?